# jQueryUi autocomplete select event fires the change event aswell. Is this a bug?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, onchange, onselect

http://jsfiddle.net/LCv8L/300/

```
$("#customer-search").autocomplete({
    source: [{
        label: "Tom Smith",
        value: "1234"},
    {
        label: "Tommy Smith",
        value: "12321"}],
    minLength: 1,
    select: function(event, ui) {
        console.log("select fired");
        console.log(ui.item);
        $("#customer-search").val(ui.item.label);
        $("#selected-customer").val(ui.item.label);        
    },
    change : function(event,ui){
        if(ui.item){
            console.log("change fired");
            console.log(ui.item);
        }
    }
});

<input type="text" id="customer-search" />
```

Please check the browser's console (F12).

The autocomplete fires the select event when an item is selected.
But once the user clicks somewhere else (after the item has been selected) the change event is also firing.

Is my code wrong or its a jquery bug???

Thanks
Arif

Comment: http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-change what do you expect other than what is written in the documentation?

Comment: Why is the change event firing with the select event when the focus is moved out from that field ?

Comment: What do you mean *firing with the select event*? The documentation is quite clear about the change event: *Triggered when the field is blurred, if the value has changed.*

Comment: Before you select an item the first time, the field is empty. So the value changes when you select the item. What don't you understand in that?